# Eclipse - Run remote PHP script after build

Tags: php, eclipse

I would like to find a way to run a remote .php script after building in Eclipse. I have a development server that runs apache/php on Linux and I write the code on a PC that does not have apahce/php installed. What I would like to be able to do is execute a php script as a last build step of the project, this script would basically perform post-build operations like temp file cleanup etc.

I have tried adding a new program builder but since I do not have a way to process php on my local machine this will not work. I do not have the option to install apache/php (or any other programs) on my local machine so everything must be done on the server. Management wants everything done in php or another "Native" process so anybody else that opens the project from the server has everything already setup.

The server is only running a LAMP stack without anything else i.e. Ruby etc.

Thanks for the help!